# I want to know which <a> Tab was clicked and get the value of that in my View and write a logic with that

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

## Search.py

```
 {% block search %}
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="bankname" type="submit" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Name
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                {% for key , value  in data_dict.items %}
                <a class="dropdown-item" value={{key}} name={{key}} href="{% url 'details' %}">{{ key}} </a>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    
    {%endblock%}
```

the number of items in data_dict is not always same , so some times it has 2 or 3 or even 10 different names which leads to 10 items in the drop down.
I need to show details of the name  clicked in the drop down in details .html

## Views.py

```
def bankdetails(request, **kwargs):
    value1 = None
    data_dict = request.session.get("data_dict")
    
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        key1 = request.GET.get("key")
        if key1 == key:
            value1 = value
    context = {"data_dict" : data_dict , "value1":value1}
    return render(request , "details.html", context )
```

i want the value of the  tab clicked in the drop-down in my view so i can display the details accordingly from my data_dict

Comment: You would need to bind an ```onchange``` Event on your dropdown and then ```POST``` the value to your views.py using ```AJAX```.

Comment: @Paolo Thanks for the reply i've already googled how to use ajax with django but i am fairly new to programming can you please show me just the part where ajax is used